# Accessing database from multiple classes

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I have created a database as follows:

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

    Connection connection = null;

    try
    {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:ebank.db");
        final Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.setQueryTimeout(30);

        statement.executeUpdate("create table if not exists employee (id integer,firstname string, lastname string, username string, password string, lgdin integer)");
//            statement.executeUpdate("insert into person values(1, 'leo')");
//            statement.executeUpdate("insert into person values(2, 'yui')");
//            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from person");

//            while(rs.next())
//            {
//                System.out.println("name = " + rs.getString("name"));
//                System.out.println("id = " + rs.getString("id"));
//            }


    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if (connection !=null)
            {
                connection.close();
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.err.println();
        }
    }
```

what I need to do is have access to this database from other classes in my application. First of all i'm trying to add two string variables from another class to this database but i can't access the statement object to do this. How would i do it?

Answer (score 2):

Define a class that handles the database with some public method to handle anything you need.

An example can be a static class with some static method, each class in your package can call directly the class.

```
public static class Database {
    public Database(String dbName){

        //HERE YOU INITIALIZE YOUR DATABASE, create the connection etc.
        // with an HSQLDB server would be something like this: change with your code.

        hsqlServer = new Server();
        hsqlServer.setDatabaseName(0, dbName);
        hsqlServer.setDatabasePath(0, "file:db/" + fileName);
    }

    public static void start(){
        //start database class
    }
    public static void connect(){
        //create the connectio, something like this:
        try {
            Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/garby", "sa", "");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (SQLException e) {

        }
    }
    public stati String getNameById(int id){
         //HERE YOU create the statement, get the name while id=id and so on, it's an example
    }
 }
```

In a class if you want to use the database you have to:

in the main method, initialize the database:

```
public static void main (String arg[]){
    new Database("name");
    Database.start();
}
```

in other class and methods just call:

```
Database.connect();
Database.myMethodToReturnSomethin();
Database.disconnect();
```

(obviously you need to have a disconnect() and a stop() methods)

With this method you can simply access the database from any class you have in the package

Answer (score 0):

Return `connection` from this class and do whatever you want in other classes.

expose `getDBConnection()` and `releaseResources(Connection connection)` methods in this class

```
public class DBConnectionManager {

    public static Connection getDBConnection() throws Exception {
        //some code to create connection
        return connection;
    }


    public static void releaseResources(Connection connection) {
        //close connection if not null
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? Do you mean define a method?

Answer (score 0):

Singleton design pattern is what you need